# Is there an established notion for the square root of a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm looking for reading I could do around the concept of square rooting a set.

I'm defining$\sqrt{A}$ to be the largest $B$ (by $\subseteq$), s.t. $B^2 \subseteq A$.

So $\sqrt{A\times B} = A \cap B$.

I'd like to know whether it has an established name, alternate descriptions, documented inequalities, etc., also can it be written as a fixed point of some set transformation function?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Then when $A$ is not itself a product, $\sqrt A = \emptyset$. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: But $\sqrt{\{(1,2),(3,1),(2,2)\}}=\{2\}$ surely?

Comment: @JoeyBF That's not necessarily so; for instance, if $A = \{\langle 1,1\rangle, 2, \langle3,5\rangle, \langle 4,4\rangle\}$, then $\sqrt{A} = \{1,4\}$ - but you're right that it's only relevant for a small group of sets $A$.

Answer (score 1):

If we insist that $A$ is a relation, i.e. a subset of $S\times S$ for some set $S$, then we can define your $\sqrt{A}$ as the largest subset of $S$ such that $A$ is reflexive on $\sqrt{A}$.